# Scroll bottom does not work on ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I found this piece of code and implemented it into my chat script. What it is meant to do is scroll to the bottom of the chat div which contains the messages of the specific chat. The chat is generated by a `chat_generate()` function which uses the `xmlhttp` protocol. The problem is that this gives me some errors. The code is as follows:

Html:

```
<button onclick="chat_generate(1);"></button>
```

JS:

```
function chat_generate(chat_id) {

    var id = chat_id.toString();
    var check_user_in = "#chat_"+id;
    if($(check_user_in).length == 0) {
        var open ="";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                /*var text = "Welcome to chat: "+myObj[1];*/
                open = [
                  "<div class='full_wrap' id='chat_"+chat_id+"'>   <div class='force-overflow'></div>    <div id='nav_"+chat_id+"' class='chat_side'>      <h2>Chat Settings & Info</h2>  <a id='closebtn' href='javascript:void(0)'",
                  "class='closebtn' onclick='chat_closeNav("+chat_id+")'>&times;</a>        <div class='authr' style='background-image:url("+myObj[3]+");'>     <a>    <div class='authr_img' style='background-image:url(pimages/"+myObj[8]+");'></div>​       </a>    <form action='mypage.php' method='post'>    <div ",
                  "class='authr_name'><button value='"+myObj[6]+"' name='userlink' class='subm_as_text'> "+myObj[6]+"</button></div>    </form>     </div>    <div class='chat_info'>    <div ",
                  "class='chat_descy'>    <h2>Chat Description</h2>    <div class='descc'>    <h3>"+myObj[2]+"</h3>    </div>    </div>    <div class='chat_fol'><h2>Chat users: 2</h2></div>    <div class='chat_back'>    <h2> ",
                  "Change Chat Wallpaper</h2>    <form method='post' action='picture.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>    <input type='file' id='upload' class='custom-file-input' name='chat_wall'>    <input type='submit' ",
                "class='chat_wall_subm' value='Change'/>    </form>    </div>    </div>    <form method='post' action='chat.php' >    <button class='chat_leave' name='chat_leave' value='$chat_index' >Leave Chat</button>    </form>    </div>    <div class='chat_mnav'>    ",
                "<span onclick='chat_openNav("+chat_id+")'>&#9776;</span>    <i class='material-icons' id='chat_un_small' onclick='chat_un_small("+chat_id+")'>arrow_upward</i>    <h1>"+myObj[1]+"</h1>    <div class='chat_close' onclick='chat_close("+chat_id+")'><i ",
                "class='material-icons' >&#xE5CD;</i></div>    </div>    <div class='conceal_wrapper'>    <div class='msgs' style='background-image:url("+myObj[4]+")' id='"+chat_id+"'>    </div>    <form method='post' id='form_"+chat_id+"' class='comform'>    <div class='chat_wcom' >    <input maxlength='140' type = 'text' id='input_"+chat_id+"'  class='comin' placeholder='My message...' name='sendmsg' onkeypress='g(event,"+chat_id+")' ",
                "autocapitalize='off' autocorrect='off'  />    <input class='hidden_index' type='text' value='"+chat_id+"' name='chat_index'/>    </div>    </form>    </div>    <div class='chat_enlarge'>    <div class='chat_enlarge_full' onmouseover='chat_action(this)' onmouseout='chat_action_negative(this)' ",
                "onclick='chat_enlarge_full("+chat_id+")'></div>    <div class='chat_enlarge_standard'  onmouseover='chat_action(this)' onmouseout='chat_action_negative(this)' onclick='chat_enlarge_standard("+chat_id+")'></div>    <div ",
                "class='chat_enlarge_small'  onmouseover='chat_action(this)' onmouseout='chat_action_negative(this)' onclick='chat_enlarge_small("+chat_id+")'></div><div class='chat_enlarge_close'  onmouseover='chat_action(this)' onmouseout='chat_action_negative(this)' onclick='chat_close("+chat_id+")'></div>    </div></div>"
                ].join("\n");

                var cusid_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('open_chat');
                if(cusid_ele.length == 0){
                  alert("No more chat space");

                }else{
                    if($(cusid_ele[0]).replaceWith(open)){
                        draggables();
                        startf();
                    }
                }
            }
            chat_enlarge_standard(chat_id);
            scrollOpen(chat_id);

        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "receivechatinfo.php?id="+id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }else{ 
        alert("The chat is already open");
    }

}

function scrollOpen(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

I believe that the problem is that the chat html is inserted in place of the `open_chat` div before the function is called resulting in an error of cannot make something to value of null. But I do not know how to solve this problem in the following case.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should try to generate a minified example with just the relevant code. That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Can you edit your post to contain a [mcve] ? For example, try adding enough imlementation to [this shell](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFFKyrLq4jL9rqfYwP9H?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue.